# Show that if a function $f:E \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ satisfies $\{x \in E : f(x) \leq y \} \in \epsilon$ $\forall y \in \mathbb{R}$ is measurable

Tags: measure-theory

> Show that if a function $f:E \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ satisfies $\{x \in E : f(x) \leq y \} \in \epsilon$ $\forall y \in \mathbb{R}$ is measurable from $(E,\epsilon)$ to $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$

**Thoughts:** I'm trying to think of a way to show that the inverse image of $f^{-1}(A)$ is in $\epsilon$ for all A in the Borrel sigma algebra, I know I could also show that $f^{-1}(A^{c})$ is in $\epsilon$ but I'm not really sure how to go about it for a function when all I know is it satisfies $\{x \in E : f(x) \leq y \} \in \epsilon$ $\forall y \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: I've never seen $\epsilon$ used to denote a $\sigma$-algebra. Well, I guess you see something new every day

Comment: The collection $\{A : \{x \in E : f(x) \in A\} \in \epsilon\}$ forms a $\sigma$-algebra and contains intervals of the form $(-\infty,y]$ for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$. Thus it contains the Borel sigma algebra $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: Makes sense, thanks.